# Android Wear: don't share all notifications

Tags: notifications, filtering, blocking, wear-os

Is it possible with Android Wear not to share all notifications with a connected wearable device? E.g. I only want only be notified of new SMS messages on the Wearable Device but not of all the other stuff?

Edit: Would it be implemented in the Smartphone App or in the Wearable App?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Wear phone app already allows you as a user to control which apps push notification to your Wear device (Android Wear app -> Settings gear in upper right -> Block app notifications).

If you mean as a developer for notifications you control, you can use [setLocalOnly(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean)) to make your notification only appear on the phone and not a Wear device.

If you mean as a developer wanting to control other application's notifications, no you cannot control which notifications bridge over to Android Wear devices, although you can cancel notifications altogether if you implement a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) (that would cancel them on both the phone and Wear device).

Comment: Yes, I mean blocking arbitrary notifications as a developer. I don't know if "context-aware notifications" is the right term for this. So e,.g., would it be possible to cancel a notification and republish it with setLocalOnly(true)?

Comment: You cannot republish notifications from another app, no.